# SQL Server : loop through one table and get the sum till threshold value is reached and update the sum value in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

`Sales` table:

[image]

`Returns` table:

[image]

I have to loop through the `Sales` table and get sum of all the `Qty` based on `Material+Batch+customer` combination until it exceeds the value of `Return_qty`, and update the `Summed` value in the `Returns` table.

This is the desired output:

[image]

As you can see, from the `Sales` table until `Sales_Invoice` 4 only it considered as it exceeded the value of `return_Qty`.

What I have tried till now?

I have tried to use while loop to loop through and calculate running total. But its not working out. Maybe approach is wrong.

Any inputs will be highly appreciated.

Comment: the sum for customer B0001 is not 106  but 126 ...  .. and the date is the actual date?  .. the key for transaction is  Material, Batch; Custumer ??

Comment: Yes the key is Material+Batch+Customer. And 106 is the sum till it exceed the return qty which is 100. Has to stop summing there itself. Till sales invoice 4. And date is actual date.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Sales TABLE
(
    [Sales_Invoice] SMALLINT
   ,[Invoice_Date] DATE
   ,[Material] VARCHAR(3)
   ,[Batch] VARCHAR(2)
   ,[Customer] VARCHAR(4)
   ,[Qty] SMALLINT
);

DECLARE @Returns TABLE
(
    [Return_Invoice] SMALLINT
   ,[Invoice_Date] DATE
   ,[Material] VARCHAR(3)
   ,[Batch] VARCHAR(2)
   ,[Customer] VARCHAR(4)
   ,[Return_Qty] SMALLINT
   ,[Sales_Qty] SMALLINT
);

INSERT INTO @Sales ([Sales_Invoice], [Invoice_Date], [Material], [Batch], [Customer], [Qty])
VALUES (1, '2019-06-07', 'AB1', 'B1', 'B001', 50)
      ,(2, '2019-06-07', 'AB1', 'B1', 'B001', 20)
      ,(3, '2019-06-06', 'AB1', 'B1', 'B001', 25)
      ,(4, '2019-06-06', 'AB1', 'B1', 'B001', 11)
      ,(5, '2019-06-06', 'AB1', 'B1', 'B001', 20)
      ,(6, '2019-06-01', 'BA2', 'C1', 'Y001', 100);

INSERT INTO @Returns ([Return_Invoice], [Invoice_Date], [Material], [Batch], [Customer], [Return_Qty])
VALUES (212, '2019-06-08', 'AB1', 'B1', 'B001', 100);

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT [Material], [Batch], [Customer]
          ,SUM([Qty]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Material], [Batch], [Customer] ORDER BY [Sales_Invoice] ASC) AS [Return_Qty]
    FROM @Sales
)
UPDATE @Returns
SET [Sales_Qty] = DS.[Return_Qty]
FROM @Returns R
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT [Material], [Batch], [Customer]
           ,MIN([Return_Qty]) AS [Return_Qty]
    FROM DataSource
    WHERE [Return_Qty] >= 100
    GROUP BY [Material], [Batch], [Customer]
) DS
    ON R.[Material] = DS.[Material]
    AND R.[Batch] = DS.[Batch]
    AND R.[Customer] = DS.[Customer];

SELECT *
FROM @Returns;
```

[image]

If you want to be more dynamical, you can use the following:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT [Material], [Batch], [Customer]
          ,SUM([Qty]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Material], [Batch], [Customer] ORDER BY [Sales_Invoice] ASC) AS [Return_Qty]
    FROM @Sales
)
UPDATE @Returns
SET [Sales_Qty] = DataSource.[Return_Qty]
FROM @Returns R
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT  DS.[Material],  DS.[Batch],  DS.[Customer]
           ,MIN(DS.[Return_Qty]) AS [Return_Qty]
    FROM DataSource DS
    WHERE  DS.[Return_Qty] >= R.[Return_Qty]
        AND R.[Material] = DS.[Material]
        AND R.[Batch] = DS.[Batch]
        AND R.[Customer] = DS.[Customer]
    GROUP BY [Material], [Batch], [Customer]
) DataSource;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Is there anyway to pass WHERE [Return_Qty] >= 100 dynamically? Rather that hard coding 100?

Answer (score 0):

you should really show your while statement in your post -  can you do that please?

I think a common table expression using recursion is a good solution for you. something along the lines of ...

```
;
WITH
cte1 AS
( 
SELECT
RANK() OVER
    (ORDER BY S.Material, S.Batch, S.Customer) GroupId,
RANK() OVER
    (
    PARTITION BY S.Material, S.Batch, S.Customer,
    ORDER BY S.INVOICE_Date) Seqn,
S.Material, S.Batch, S.Customer, S.qty, R.Return_qty
FROM
    Sales S
JOIN
    Returns R
    ON S.Material = R.Material AND S.Batch = R.Batch AND S.Customer = R.Customer
),
cte2 AS
( 
SELECT
GroupId, Seqn,Material, Batch, Customer, qty AS TriggeringQty, Return_qty
FROM cte1 
WHERE seqn  =1
UNION ALL
SELECT
cte1.GroupId, cte1.Seqn, cte1.Material, cte1.Batch, cte1.Customer,
    cte1.qty + cte2.qty, cte1.Return_qty
FROM cte2
    JOIN cte1
    ON cte1.GroupId = cte2.GroupID AND cte1.seqn = cte2.seqn+1
WHERE 
cte2.qty < 100 AND cte1.seqn + cte2.seqn+1 >= Return_qty )

UPDATE R
SET R.Sales_qty = cte2.triggeringqty
FROM Returns R
JOIN cte2 S ON
S.Material = R.Material AND S.Batch = R.Batch AND S.Customer = R.Customer
WHERE cte2.triggeringqty >= 100;
```

Sorry I haven't tried the above so probably won't run, but hopefully you see what's happening.